# Quicksight embedded dashboard not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have tried to embed a dashboard into but i am getting the following error inside the iFrame

[image]

Steps i have done:

1. Created the dashboard and shared with the users.
2. Whitelisted my domain.
3. List the users using `aws cli` to get their ARNs using the following command

   `aws quicksight list-users --aws-account-id=717381691678 --namespace=default`
4. After the getting the ARN, i have called the command to get the embed url.

   `aws quicksight get-dashboard-embed-url --aws-account-id 717381691678 --dashboard-id b29f1bd1-e6d3-4091-a51e-9d954XXXX46b --identity-type QUICKSIGHT --user-arn "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:71738169XXX:user/default/XXX"`
5. The above command successfully responded with embed URL, I then added the URL to Quicksight embedding sdk:

```
var options = {
    url: realylongurl.com,
    container: document.getElementById("graphContainer"),
    scrolling: "no",
    height: "700px",
    width: "1000px"
};
var dashboard = QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(options);
```

I know that the URL has only 5 minute before expiring, but i am sure that i tested before that.

I am only using cli because, currently it in the process of development, i will soon change this into NodeJS SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, it was due to my region configured wrong. Changed the region in the  `config` file, now it is working fine.

Comment: I have same issue, but I found my region is correct. the UI is refused to display iframe.